# Change Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate from Italian to English?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in Italian and want to change it to English. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tools > Options > International Settings**

Or:

**Strumenti > Opzioni > Click Mostra Tutte le impostazioni (i.e Show all settings) > Impostazioni Internazionali**

Select Windows Language, press OK, and restart Visual Studio.

[image]

[image]